# Slideshow / setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, setattribute

I got a problem with my slideshow and i don't understand why the console give me the error message : setAttribute is not a function on my method ( of my class Slider ).

Can you give me some help please ?

Thanks a lot .
Nelson

```
    nextImageOnClic(imagesTable)
{
    this.rightChevron.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currentImage += 1;
        if(currentImage >= imagesTable.length)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        this.image.setAttribute("src", imagesTable[currentImage]);
    })
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.image` defined?

Comment: this.image is in my class =         this.image = document.getElementsByClassName(image);

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return multiple elements. You will need to pick one out of the list before you can use `setAttribute` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)